# Swift UI - canvas does not build

Tags: ios, canvas, swiftui

LaunchExternalToolError: Failed to build SplashView.swift

Failed to launch swiftc.

==================================

| HumanReadableNSError: NSInvalidArgumentException |
| --- |
| com.apple.dt.PreviewsFoundation.ExceptionError (0): |
| ==NSLocalizedFailureReason: too many arguments (5195) -- limit is 4096 |

Comment: any response ????